# How can I set this image to activity in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

I'm downloading file using Async on android, Now i want this files to display on activity. How can I do this inside onSucess method? I tried below method but image is not showing!

```
AsyncHttpClient fileDownload = new AsyncHttpClient();
String[] allowedContentTypes = new String[] { "image/png", "image/jpeg" };
fileDownload.get("http://server.com/file.png", new BinaryHttpResponseHandler(allowedContentTypes)           {
       @Override
       public void onSuccess(byte[] fileData) {
        //Do Something here to view files in activity   
       ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.imageview1);   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
AsyncHttpClient fileDownload = new AsyncHttpClient();
String[] allowedContentTypes = new String[] { "image/png", "image/jpeg" };
fileDownload.get("http://server.com/file.png", new BinaryHttpResponseHandler(allowedContentTypes) {
       @Override
       public void onSuccess(byte[] fileData) {
        //Do Something here to view files in activity  
         Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(fileData,0,fileData.length); 
         ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.imageview1);
         img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either place an [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) in your XML layout or create one dynamically and add it to the activity. Then simply set the image for the ImageView to display.